# Faulting thread stack-trace using IDebugControl::GetStackTrace

Tags: stack-trace, crash-dumps, minidump

I have a minidump of crashed application and I would like to analyse it using DbgEng in my own library. Does anyone now how can I get the stacktrace of the thread that caused the program crash using IDebugControl::GetStackTrace?

I appreciate any kind of help

Thx

Comment: OK, I have a solution now.

The solution is described in this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/11/10/minidumps-and-bad-stacks.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the crash dump was generated, it might be using embedded contexts. Use the [`IDebugControl4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface which gives you access to the [`GetStoredEventInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548431.aspx) and [`GetContextStackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545748.aspx) methods. If `GetStoredEventInformation` fails, you can fall back on the [`GetStackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548425.aspx) method.

The solution is described in this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/11/10/minidumps-and-bad-stacks.aspx

Comment: The link is dead.